# Deploying umbraco site to production database

Tags: database, deployment, umbraco

We have an umbraco site connected to MSSQL databases, which have three phases:

1) **Local:**
This site is connected to a database running on our syst-server and is for our developers to mess around with as intended. This database is pretty much for testing and messing around

2) **Syst:**
This site is pretty much a deployed version of the local site, still connected to our syst-database. This is for our testing team to ensure everything looks good (apart from stuff like product data, since we will be creating a lot of test products in syst).

3) **Production:**
This is where the magic happens. We have a seperate database for production, which has valid data for our company.

Now my question is:
How would I sync umbraco changes made to our production database, whilst not syncing products? Is there a smart tool made for syncing only umbraco data, and keeping out custom data?

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco Courier - https://umbraco.com/products/umbraco-courier/.

You can pick exactly what you want to push to the production site.